# How to format table cell value to HH:MM

Tags: java

I have a `jspinner` in a `jtable` column.  While editing `jspinner` it is showing 
`07:20:14(HH:MM:SS)` and after selecting another cell it is writing in the cell value something like `Fri mar 01 07:20:14 IST 2016`.

But I want to format this to same like `jspinner` value. How to do it?
[write value in jtable same as in jspinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JJNq.png)

```
   TableColumn col3=DailydatasTbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
   col3.setPreferredWidth(150);
   col3.setCellEditor(new Spinnerex());
   public class Spinnerex extends AbstractCellEditor implement  TableCellEditor{
   private JSpinner spinner;
   private SpinnerDateModel model;
   private SimpleDateFormat format;

    public Spinnerex() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    model = new SpinnerDateModel();
    model.setValue(date);
    spinner = new JSpinner(model);
    format = ((JSpinner.DateEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getFormat();

    format.applyPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    }



    Object Valueactual;

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {

         return spinner.getValue();

    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable jtable, Object o, boolean bln, int i, int i1) {

        return spinner;
   }
```

}

Comment: [Specifying Spinner Formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html#format)

Answer (score 0):

Adding TableCellRenderer solved my problem.

```
enter code here
class DateRenderer implements TableCellRenderer
 {

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object  value,boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

JPanel c = new JPanel();

if (value instanceof Date)
    {


 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
 c.add(new JLabel(dateFormat.format(value)));

    }

    return c;
   }
```

And call this class like

```
enter code here
  YourTableName.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(new DateRenderer());
```